# Why are surnames often misspellings of English words?

Tags: orthography, names, surnames, derivation

Why do English surnames so often seem to be derived from slight misspellings of common English words?

- *Weekes*
- *Thorne*
- *Browne*
- *Lilley*
- *Keene*
- *Paige*
- *Lowe*
- *Hooke*
- *Hawthorne*
- *Sargent*
- *Whyte*
- *Chappell*
- *Horne*

*ad infinitum*...

Comment: Most likely because they are correct spellings from 500-1000 years ago.

Comment: I wouldn't quite say they are *misspellings*

Comment: ... Arguably, the 'common English words' come closer to  'misspellings'. They're usually the ones that have changed.